# Clone an outdated mirror repository to archive it

Tags: kali-linux, mirror

Kali Linux 1.0.0 is now End of Life but they had setup an archive mirror for it. It will no longer be maintained, but in version 2.0 some of my dependencies seems to fail and I can't fix it.

My question is: can I clone the archive mirror as it is right now for my personal use? I mean, that if I will setup version 1.0 again I will use this URL to update it. And if it's possible, please lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `debmirror` to mirror any Debian-style repo.

Install it, point it at your upstream Kali 1.0 mirror, and tell it to store the mirror somewhere your ftpd and/or httpd can provide access to it.

> Package: debmirror
>
> Description-en: Debian partial mirror script, with
> ftp and package pool support  This program downloads and maintains a
> partial local Debian mirror.  It can mirror any combination of
> architectures, distributions and  sections. Files are transferred by
> ftp, http, hftp or rsync, and package  pools are fully supported. It
> also does locking and updates trace files.

By 'partial mirror', it means anything up to and including a full mirror...but you don't have to mirror the entire archive (including all architectures) if you don't want to.

Comment: Have i to setup keyrings like mentioned in this tutorial? http://lgallardo.com/en/2012/12/06/como-crear-un-mirror-de-debian-y-ubuntu-con-debmirror/

Comment: yes, but use Kali's keys rather than debian's or ubuntu's.

Comment: Sorry i have edited my question. Should i ask for keyrings in a separate question?